# The appropriate word for violating a clause, condition or rule

Tags: word-choice, terminology, synonyms, formality

If you have a contract (which has a number of clauses), or a guideline that has rules. When one *violates* a rule or a *violates* a clause, is there a better way of describing it than to use the word "violate"? What's the appropriate term here?

My case: Respondents were requested to limit their responses to 5 pages.  ProviderX **violated** this **condition.**

the two words I am trying to replace are: "violated" and "condition" (I feel like "condition" is too preliminary. The supplier in this case has violated a rule.

Comment: See what synonyms fit there. _contravene, breach, infringe, break, transgress, overstep, disobey, defy, flout; disregard, ignore, trample on_

Comment: I'd say **_disregarded_**

Comment: @NVZ I'm not looking for a synonym. I was looking for a proper term. Sure, you can even say "broke" , but I'm trying to compose a formal letter, not just pick a word that fits.

Comment: @NVZ "disregarded" sounds very, very close to perfect.. I think that's actually probably the answer. Thank you

Comment: But since it's about contracts, _violate_ is the most "appropriate" IMHO.

Comment: @NVZ Lawyers don't use "violate" in correspondence when acting on behalf of lay clients. Likewise, litigation uses the word "breach" in the pleadings, etc.

Comment: @LearnByReading A thesaurus might be more valuable than you think. Mine lists disregarded, along with "contravene, breach, infringe, break, transgress, overstep, disobey, defy" under "violate".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lawyers and commercial movers and shakers use *breach* or *breach of a term* or a *breach of a contractual term* in their lexicons. Any legally enforceable agreement is a contract and vice-versa. Likewise, a *condition* in this context is synonymous with a *term* and I consider that the OP may confidently substitute *breach* for *violate* or, where there is no legal sanction or consequence arising out of a mere *guideline*, then I would use *ignore or ignored* for failing to abide by "non-legal" guidelines.

**Breach:**   "an act of breaking or failing to observe a law, **agreement** [emphasis added], or code of conduct." (Oxford Dictionaries)